# Ubuntu is unable to boot up after sudden power outage

Tags: boot

Ubuntu shows me this message:

[image: Ubuntu shows me this message]

systemctl status Network Manager logs

[image: systemctl status Network Manager logs]

Comment: my Ubuntu version is 18.04

Comment: am facing the same problem.. any helps? I have faced this problem for more than 2 times already. I dont want to reinstall the whole OS again..

Comment: reinstall the os fixed !

Comment: I would like to make use of the terminal or live CD to fix something and do not want to reinstlal the pacakages again